# Jquery sum multiple rows of multiple drop down fields

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, drop-down-menu, sum

I found some really good sum row, sum column of drop down examples, but nothing on sum row and grand total of drop downs. I'm not very good at jQuery but learning.

I have many rows of dropdowns for days of the week, each is a work shift. I need to total the row of shifts. Then sum the column of total hours.

I read that 'select' is not like an input so most of the sum row examples I saw did not work.

I need a working example like this. I'll be using php to loop the rows so its important to address the rows (by id? by class?)  Have pity and show a newbie how its done...thanks all.

Here is the table:

```
<table >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Mon</th>
            <th>Tue</th>
            <th>Wed</th>
            <th>Thur</th>
            <th>Fri</th>
            <th>Sat</th>
            <th>Sun</th>
            <th>Hours</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>r1</th>
            <td> <select>
        <option value="8">9-5</option>
        <option value="9">9-6</option>
        <option value="10">9-7</option>
        </select></td>
            <td> <select>
        <option value="8">9-5</option>
        <option value="9">9-6</option>
        <option value="10">9-7</option>
        </select></td>
          <td><select >
            <option value="8">9-5</option>
        <option value="9">9-6</option>
        <option value="10">9-7</option>
          </select></td>
            <td><select>
              <option value="8">9-5</option>
        <option value="9">9-6</option>
        <option value="10">9-7</option>
            </select></td>
            <td><select >
              <option value="8">9-5</option>
        <option value="9">9-6</option>
        <option value="10">9-7</option>
            </select></td>
            <td><select >
              <option value="8">9-5</option>
        <option value="9">9-6</option>
        <option value="10">9-7</option>
            </select></td>
            <td><select >
              <option value="8">9-5</option>
        <option value="9">9-6</option>
        <option value="10">9-7</option>
            </select></td>
            <td> 40</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>r2</th>
            <td><select>
                <option value="8">9-5</option>
                <option value="9">9-6</option>
                <option value="10">9-7</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td><select>
                <option value="8">9-5</option>
                <option value="9">9-6</option>
                <option value="10">9-7</option>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td><select >
                <option value="8">9-5</option>
                <option value="9">9-6</option>
                <option value="10">9-7</option>
            </select></td>
            <td><select >
                <option value="8">9-5</option>
                <option value="9">9-6</option>
                <option value="10">9-7</option>
            </select></td>
            <td><select >
                <option value="8">9-5</option>
                <option value="9">9-6</option>
                <option value="10">9-7</option>
            </select></td>
            <td><select>
                <option value="8">9-5</option>
                <option value="9">9-6</option>
                <option value="10">9-7</option>
            </select></td>
            <td><select>
                <option value="8">9-5</option>
                <option value="9">9-6</option>
                <option value="10">9-7</option>
            </select></td>
          <td>40</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>s</th>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>80</td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to run it at once, there is a code example for your case:

```
$('table tbody tr').each(function(){
  var sum = 0;
  $('option:selected', this).attr('value', function(i,v){
    sum += parseInt(v);
  });

  $('td:last', this).text(sum)
})
```

**Update** - code with real-time click event and each and total sums recalculate

See work example here: http://jsfiddle.net/6HAPV/2

```
HoursSum = {
  table:    $('table'),
  row:      $('table tbody tr'),
  totalSum: $('table td:last'),

  init: function(){
    this.row.each(function(){
      HoursSum.calculate(this)
    });
    HoursSum.rebuildEvent();
    HoursSum.totalSumEvent();
  },

  rebuildEvent: function(){
    $('select', this.row).bind('change',function(){
      HoursSum.calculate($(this).parents('tr'));
    })
  },

  calculate: function(obj){
    var sum = 0;
    $('option:selected', obj).attr('value', function(i,v){
      sum += parseInt(v);
    });
    $('td:last', obj).text(sum);
    HoursSum.table.trigger('sumChanged', sum);
  },

  totalSumEvent: function(){
    HoursSum.table.bind('sumChanged', function(){
      v = 0;
      HoursSum.row.find('td:last').each(function(){
        v += parseInt($(this).text())
      })
      HoursSum.totalSum.text(v)
    });
  }
}

HoursSum.init()
```

Comment: if you need to recalculate the sum every change on select box, just bind the function to "click" event

Comment: @Chandresh what jQuery version do you use?

Comment: **jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js**

Comment: @Chandresh upgrade you jQuery to 1.6+

Comment: Wow, thanks for the great and fast replies. However, its not quite working. On load the rows calculate a 'NaN' value. On select, the the NaN atemps to change but returns to NaN. So something is not calculating? Do I need id's or names?  It seems so close, I'll keep at it.  I've started the example here...  http://jsfiddle.net/k9kA2/2/     ..... so you can see my issue, let me know what you find...thanks guys. This seem to silly to be holding me up.  I'll get it eventually.

Comment: man you are a hero! Do you have a site where I can make a donation?

Comment: you are welcome on Stackoverflow :) best donation is a reputation here

Answer (score 0):

My reading comprehension is terrible right now I'm so tired I had no idea what you were asking for and it's my fault but I hope this is what you want.

EDIT: I didn't see that the number of hours worked was in the name attribute so I was calculating hours worked based on the value.

```
$(function(){

    $('select').change(function(){
        renderHours();
    });

    function renderHours() {

        var totalHours = 0;
        $('tbody').children('tr').each(function(){


            var rowHours = 0;
            $("option:selected", $(this)).each(function(){

                var str = $(this).val();
                totalHours += str;
                rowHours += str;
            });

            $('td:last', $(this)).html(rowHours);
        });
        $('td:last').html(totalHours);


    }
    renderHours();
});
```

Comment: you can use **val()** instead of **text()** with transformation

Comment: why not use val() instead of text()..? is anything special purpose for writing 3-4 line more code..?

Comment: @Mikhailov You sure about this??! val() is giving me the name attribute, not the value. EDIT: Sorry.. I'm confused.. is that script doing the wrong thing?

Comment: **val()** returns the hours "8", "9", "10"

Comment: good tip for you - iterate by attributes, not by selected options